# re.sub with Japanese Characters

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string:

```
s = u'アガサ・クリスティー　奥さまは名探偵　～パディントン発4時50分～（字幕版）'
```

However, when I try and get rid of the character `（` and everything after it, it doesn't match:

```
>>> print re.sub(r'\（.+$', '', s)
アガサ・クリスティー　奥さまは名探偵　～パディントン発4時50分～（字幕版）
```

How would I get the string to be just:

```
アガサ・クリスティー　奥さまは名探偵　～パディントン発4時50分～
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should ensure that all of the parameters to `re.sub()` are the same type -- `str` or `unicode`. Try this:

```
# encoding: utf-8

import re
s = u'アガサ・クリスティー　奥さまは名探偵　～パディントン発4時50分～（字幕版）'
print re.sub(ur'\（.+$', u'', s)
```

Comment: Thank you. This fixes the issue.

Comment: That is true, @ccf, but it doesn't work if you do `re.sub(ur'\（.+$', '（）', s)`. So I `unicode`-ify all of the args, just in case.